# jQuery swapping ids

Tags: jquery, attr

I have swapping div's. When I click the `#inactive` id, the `#active-page` should disappear and the `#inactive-page` should appear. Moreover, the `#active id` should become the `#inactive` id and vice versa. I have used swapping id's =>`#inactive-page-swap` with the qualities of `#inactive-page` and `#active-swap` with qualities of `#active`.

THE PROBLEM IS - when I click the `#inactive` id, the `#active-page` disappears but the `#inactive-page` does not appear.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#inactive").click(function(){
        $(#inactive).attr("id","active-swap");
        $("#active").attr("id","inactive");
        $("#active-swap").attr("id","active");
        $("#active-page").attr("id","inactive-page-swap",function(){
            $("#inactive-page").attr("id","active-page");
            $("#inactive-page-swap").attr("id","inactive-page");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: you are missing quotes around your #inactive. Also, you should be swapping classes not id's.

Comment: Also the event handler is added to the element, not to the `id` property, so even if you swap the id the click handler will fire only for the original `#inactive` element

Comment: But the inactive id will become active and the active id shall become inactive id after the working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#inactive").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        inactive = $('#inactive');
        active = $('#active');
        swap = $('#active-swap');
        inactive.attr('id', 'active-swap');
        active.attr('id', 'inactive');
        swap.attr('id', 'active');
        inactive = $('#active-page');
        inactivepage = $('#inactive-page');
        inactiveswap = $('#inactive-page-swap');
        $(inactive).attr("id","inactive-page-swap");
        $(inactivepage).attr("id","active-page");
        $(inactiveswap).attr("id","inactive-page");
    });
});
```

see this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/m52jp/2/)